# Capturing entire d3 graph when printing

Tags: css, printing, d3.js

I'm trying to write a `print.css` stylesheet for an application that has a lot of d3 graphs.  I've experimented with settings widths to `100%`, different `pt` values, etc, but I just can't get the entire graph to display on the print preview.  Any hints on how to style the svg/container in order to get the entire thing printed on a normal 8.5x11?

Thanks a ton.  Picture below: The x-axis actually goes to 2013, and the graph gets cut off when printing as you can see

[image: The x-axis actually goes to 2013, and the graph gets cut off when printing as you can see]

Comment: It sounds like you would want to modify the code to resize the graph to fit the page.

Answer (score 2):

Edited...

My original suggestion was:

```
svg#time-series-graph {
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

This doesn't work across browsers. If I understand it correctly, the `transform` attribute is not actually in the SVG specification as something that can be changed using CSS (although it seems to work in Firefox).

An ugly alternative would be to render two charts: one that's only visible on screen and a smaller one that's only visible with print.css. There must be a better way to do it!

Comment: This stylization isn't working, even if I add it outside _print.scss

Comment: That's what I tried.  When I inspect element (on Chrome) it just has the stylization crossed-out... doesn't make any sense... nothing else should be overriding it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be. Are you able to post a link to the page?

Comment: I'm not able to do that yet, sorry.  I'll comment again if anything new comes up, but until then, I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

This was the top result for my search so I'm adding the solution I've found. Adding a `width: 670px;`on the containing element makes it fit.